# How to pass variable as Key to hash in perl

Tags: linux, perl

```
my $host =`hostname | cut -c8-10`;
      my %envin = ('dev','dev','stg','stage','prd','prod');
      print $envin{'$host'};
```

Output :

> Use of uninitialized value in print at host.pl line 7.

Unable to pass the variable as key to hash

Regards,
kalai

Answer (score 6):

- You're quoting `$host` with single quotes. It therefore won't be interpolated. You want `$envin{$host}` instead. `$envin{"$host"}` would work, but the quotes are redundant.
- `$host` might have a linefeed. (`chomp` will fix)
- usually a hash is more clearly written like this:

  ```
  my %envin = (
      'dev' => 'dev',
      'stg' => 'stage',
      'prd' => 'prod', 
  );
  ```

Comment: True. A useful feature, but I tend to leave quotes in, just because I think it clearer.

Comment: Hi Sobrique, i used hash which you said. and print $envin{$host};
but again same error ..

Comment: i m getting output of print $host  is dev. ya.its given

Comment: from the command line, run "  hostname | cut -c8-10  " and tell us what it prints

Comment: $host will have a newline at the end; remove it with chomp before using it as the hash key.  A good way to inspect values is `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $host`